# SQL Statement in Delphi throwing "missing semi-colon" error

Tags: sql, ms-access, delphi-5

I am pulling data into a new MS Access database from a previous Access database.  I am inserting old transaction data into the new table using a SQL statement which looks correct and will work in MS Access directly, but when I execute it in Delphi (5) I get an OLE error stating that there is a missing semi-colon at the end of the statement.
I have hunted through all the answers to similar questions on several sites, but nothing seems to be relevant to this problem.  I'd be grateful if someone could cast an eye over the code and the statement and perhaps spot my error.

```
    with InsertQuery do begin
        Close;
        SQLStr := 'insert into trans (Transactionid, saleid,productcode, barcode, description, salequantity, price,';
        SQLStr := SQLStr + 'SalePrice, category, transdate, taxrate, receiptText) values (';
        SQLStr := SQLStr + IntToStr(TransNo)+','+IntToStr(SaleNo)+','+QuotedStr(PCode)+','+QuotedStr(Bcode)+','+QuotedStr(Desc)+',';
        SQLStr := SQLStr + IntToStr(Qty)+','+FloatToStrF(PPrice,ffFixed,10,2)+','+FloatToStrF(PPrice,ffFixed,10,2)+',';
        SQLStr := SQLStr + QuotedStr(Cat)+','+FormatDateTime('#'+'yyyy-mm-dd'+'#',sDate)+',';
        SQLStr := SQLStr + QuotedStr('E')+','+QuotedStr(RText)+')';
        SQL.Add(SQLStr);
        ExecSQL;
     end;
```

Here is the query generated above.  Taken from inspection of the variable SQLStr:

```
insert into trans (transactionid, saleid, productcode, barcode, salequantity, price, saleprice, 
category, transdate, taxrate, receiptText) values (2728,1034,'BPG 27/03/2020','BPG 27/03/2020',1,8.00,8.00,'Clubs and Classes',#2019-08-23#,'E','BPGroup 27/03/2020')
```

As I stated above, running the query above in Access works fine.

Any help, pointers very much appreciated.   Thank you.

Comment: You really should be using a parameterized query instead, and not formatting the values manually at all.

Comment: Perhaps, but I know SQL better than I know Delphi.   Delphi 5's parameterised queries have caused me problems.   I'm not worried about injection issues because this code is going to executed once and then it will be removed.

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with SQL. A ; at end of SQL statement should not be needed (but wouldn't hurt) so no idea why this error is triggered. If this is a one-time event, why use Delphi? Why not just have Access import objects or data?

Comment: I would like to have just used Access, but I'm not good at VBA and there is quite a lot of sorting going on before this query is populated.    Of course, I tried adding the semicolon at the end of the statement first off when the error occurred.   I suspect that the error has very little to do with semicolons - that the semicolon error is the catch-all for other errors.   This is why I wanted someone else to look at the code.   I broke the query down to just putting the key values in and still got the same error.  But thanks for responding.

Comment: I meant, why use code at all? Use Access ExternalData to link or import. Why import and not just make a copy of file? It would be faster to accomplish manually than to write a bunch of code. How is sorting relevant?

Comment: It's coming from several different files and each has its own format.   I want all the transactions in one table with one format.   I've already imported the tables I'm using from the original MDB files, as you suggest.    But I can't use them in that format.   I thought about creating a master reference file, but - why not just have the data in a useful format?   Which is why I'm doing this. Sorting is relevant because there are good business reasons for doing it - believe me.   Business requirements, mate!   I've just about talked them into moving it to MySQL so that's the next thing.

Comment: BTW, the sorting is not just the order of the data.   It's much more complex than that.

Comment: Why not having your Delphi program generate a text file with all the SQL statement and then use Access to execute the statements in that text file?

Comment: Actually, I worked out what the problem was this morning - I hadn't cleared the previous SQL statement from the query!   It was that simple.   You shouldn't do things when you're tired, I guess.   Thanks for the responses.   All were good points and I'm grateful.